# Positive alternative to "ominous"

Tags: synonyms

The word `ominous` has a negative connotation attached to it, but is there a word with the same kind of meaning that is positive?

Comment: These are answers, @Josh61. _Encouraging_, _promising_ and _hopeful_ are more colloquial synonyms that would often work.

Comment: glance in a thesaurus.

Comment: I think *portentous* is of neutral connotation, but [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/portentous#Adjective) may suggest otherwise:  “Of momentous or ominous significance. ... Ominously prophetic.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Propitious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/propitious) is one option:

> Presenting favorable circumstances; auspicious.

Source:The American Heritage® Dictionary

Comment: *Auspicious* in that definition seems an even better option.

Comment: right, auspicious is probably what Jim had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Serendipitous : Occurring or discovered by chance in a happy or beneficial way.

Auspicious : Conducive to success; favorable. Giving or being a sign of future success.